# How to select an option from dropdownlist of a webpage in perl scripting using Selenuium::Remote::Driver

Tags: perl, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select one option from the dropdown list of a webpage in perl scripting using Selenuium::Remote::Driver  But it shows an error as"Error while executing command: Server returned error code 404 and no data at D:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/WebElement.pm line 46."
can you please suggest me how to solve it,
Thanks in advance..

**Webprogram.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Remote::WebElement;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);


my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver;
$driver->get("https://api.clickandbuy-t2.com/api-testclient/");
$driver->set_implicit_wait_timeout(40000);
my $title2 = $driver->get_title;
print  $title2;
my $x=is($driver->get_title,'ClickandBuy PAY API Test Tool',"Title");
print $x;
if ($x==1)
{
   print"api test client is  opened";
   my $sd="S1";
  $driver->find_element('mainForm:connectURL','id')->set_selected($sd)->click();#error shown for this command

}
```

output as"ClickandBuy PAY API Test Toolok 1 - Title
1api test client is  opened Error while executing command: Server returned error code 404 and no data at D:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/WebElement.pm line 46."

Comment: Is it that the dropdownlist is populated with javascript? can you show the HTML source you are testing against?

Comment: <tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<select id="mainForm:connectURL" style="" onchange="flipOtherConnectURL('Others')" size="1" name="mainForm:connectURL">
<option value="">Select Server </option>
<option value="D1">D1</option>
<option value="D2">D2</option>
<option value="T1">T1</option>
<option value="T2">T2</option>
<option value="S1">S1</option>
<option value="P1">P1</option>
<option value="Local Host 8080">Local Host 8080</option>
<option value="Local Host 8180">Local Host 8180</option>
<option value="Others">Other Server URL</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>

Comment: I have provided HTML code for that dropdown list in the above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with perl, but other webdriver implementations behave funny when selecting options from a dropdown, you don't need to do the set_selected step, try just clicking straight on the option by finding it with an xpath:

```
$driver->find_element("//select[@id='mainForm:connectURL']/option[@value='".$sd."']")->click();
```

Comment: no problem, please mark my answer as correct if that's what the problem was :)